# Joins existing TcpChannel

Tags: c#, remoting

Our costumer has Citrix environment
For first time application starts it opens a TcpChannel with port 8500 OK. When application runs again (with different process ID) of course open Channel is not possible. But is it possible to "Join" or "Merge" to existing channel?

How do I listen the same port with TcpChannel

Here is the how im registering the channel

```
mChannel = new TcpChannel(8500);
                ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(mChannel, false);

                mi_Transfer = new Remote.cTransfer();
                mService = RemotingServices.Marshal(mi_Transfer, "GenerateBarcode");
```

Comment: Can you give a larger sense of what you're trying to accomplish?  I don't think it will be possible to use the same port for `TcpChannels` in two different processes, but if you can clarify your goal, we may be able to provide an alternative solution.

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach thanks for reply.
This is a long story, I know instead Remoting I can use WCF
Goal is, COM Object should Transfer data (which is coming from SAP) to the Application
This app can be start or reused.
Each start of app runs TcpChannel (if port is free)
With Citrix client we have several running application but only one able to listen incoming "transfers"

Comment: If multiple instances of the application are running on the same Citrix environment, what is the desired behavior?  Should all instances see the incoming transfers, or should they be routed to a specific instance somehow?

Comment: 1. Transfer means raise some event or method in App with some arguments
2. Yes all transfer should routed to a specific (find process by username) running Application
3. Give each of them specific port (or random) is not possible, client range are 0-200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, I would suggest creating a Windows Service (in .NET, a class extending `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase`), and having the service host the `TcpChannel` on port 8500.  Then, have each instance of the application that starts up use a dynamic port and register with the service, providing it the user name of the user who launched the application.  The service can then use the user names to route the requests it receives on port 8500 to the appropriate instance of the application on the dynamic port.

Comment: In this case TcpChannel should start when Service runs first time? Or Each Application run?

Comment: There will only be one instance of the service, so it will start the `TcpChannel` on port 8500.  Each instance of the application that starts up will host another `TcpChannel` on a dynamic port.  The service will receive all of the incoming "Transfers" and route them to an instance of the application based on the user name.  This will require creating some logic in the server to register instances of the application, and require changing the application to tell the service about itself on startup.

Comment: I understood. Thanks @Aaron